# Integrating CoinGate Payment Gateway in PHP Project: Including Payment Fees in Total Amount

Tags: php, payment-gateway

I'm integrating CoinGate into my PHP project for payment processing. Currently, the payment fee is deducted from the paid amount, but I want to adjust the setup so that the payment fee is included in the total amount that the customer pays. How can I achieve this configuration within my PHP project using CoinGate? Any guidance, code examples, or relevant documentation would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

`$amount = $_GET['amount']; $feePercentage = 0.01; // 1% $fee = $amount * $feePercentage; $totalAmount = $amount + $fee;`

I implemented the above code snippet in my PHP project to calculate the total amount including a 1% fee. However, upon testing the setup, I found that the fee is also being charged for the 1% of the fee itself, resulting in an incorrect total amount.

Comment: That's simple maths: (a * 1.01 * 0.01) <> a * 0.01